# How to scalably consider nulls in equals()?

Tags: java, generics, nullpointerexception, null, equals

To avoid a null pointer exception in my `equals()`, I have to consider the possibility of one or more nulls.

Is there a scalable way for considering nulls? The following code will become ugly quite fast if I add more type parameters.

```
  public boolean equals(Pair<T, U> p) {

    boolean firstIsEqual, secondIsEqual;

    if (p.getFirst()==null) {
      firstIsEqual = first == null;
    }
    else {
      firstIsEqual = (first!=null) && (first.equals(p.getFirst()));
    }

    // copy-paste...
    if (p.getSecond()==null) {
      secondIsEqual = second == null;
    }
    else {
      secondIsEqual = (second!=null) && (second.equals(p.getSecond()));
    }

    return (firstIsEqual && secondIsEqual);
  }
```

Comment: This is not a valid `equals` for the standard uses; using `@Override` will help prevent this problem. Assuming that `Pair` is your own class, then (after the appropriate type checking you'll have to add) I'd just write `return Objects.equals(this.first, p.first) && Objects.equals(this.second, p.second);`.

Comment: @chrylis if I override, I will have to cast `Object` to `Pair` ("unchecked cast" warning). Isn't this something one should avoid?

Comment: That's not an unchecked cast, which is about generics. Generally yes, you should avoid it, but in `equals(Object)` it's unavoidable. If you don't override (and override `hashCode`), you certainly won't get the behavior you're expecting.

Answer (score 0):

The only solution that scale are:

- to use a library like Lombok that provide means to generate such methods during the compile phase
- to use the built-in code generation features of your IDE

Seriously: nobody in the real world writes equals/hashCode methods manually. You use a tool and tell that which fields should be used in the computation. If a field is added, you have to remember to re-generate the methods.

Or you use a jvm language that supports data classes such as Kotlin or Scala.